# Vue slot-scope with v-for, data changed but not re-rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a question while I'm studying vuejs2

I made an example with slot-scope && v-for, but it has an error which I can't understand.

Here is example code
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/6839/

app.vue

```html
<template id="list-template">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <slot name="row" v-for="item in list" v-bind=item />
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <list-component :list="list">
    <li slot="row" slot-scope="item">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="h(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </list-component>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('list-component', {
  template: '#list-template',
   props: {
      list: {
        type: Array
      }
   }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
        list: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Cherry'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Durian'},
        {id: 5, name: 'Eggplant'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    h (item) {
      item.name = item.name.toUpperCase()
      console.log('Changed!')
      console.log(item)
    }
  }
});
```

Strange thing is, the method 'h' is triggered and then, the console said 'Changed!' and data also changed but, the view is not re-rendered.

What am I missing? I think slot-scoped object data is not referencing the original object data.

What should I do to modify the original data?

Thanks for reading this question.

Comment: you have to listen click event from the component

Answer (score 1):

You are directly trying to modify the value of an item in an array. Due to some [limitations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) vue cannot detect such array modifications.

So update your code to use `vm.$set()` to make chamges to the array item.

```
methods: {
    h (item) {
      let i = this.items.findIndex((it) => it.id === item.id);
      this.$set(this.list, i, {...item, name: item.name.toUpperCase()});
    console.log(item.id)
  }
```

Here is the u[pdated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/7065/)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to modify data without search index?